# How would I turn this lambda function to a simple function?

Tags: java, lambda

I'm trying to understand lambda formatting in Java and could really use some help converting this function into a standard function to see how this works:

```
Callback<ListView<Contacts>, ListCell <Contacts>> factory = lv -> new ListCell<>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Contacts item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        setText(empty ? "-" :( "[" + item.getContactID() + "] " + item.getContactName()));
    }
};
```

Comment: If you convert the lambda to a regular function you cannot directly assign it to `factory`.  More context is needed to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: are you using the lambda parameter `lv`? why not start with a `new Callback<>(){}` implementation and then transform the code for readability.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the code to create an anonymous [`Callback`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/Callback.html) object:

```
Callback<ListView<Contacts>, ListCell<Contacts>> factory = new Callback<>() {
    @Override
    public ListCell<Contacts> call(ListView<Contacts> lv) {
    }
};
```

Then paste in the right hand side of the `->` lambda operator as `call()`'s method body. The only modification needed is to make it a `return` statement:

```
Callback<ListView<Contacts>, ListCell<Contacts>> factory = new Callback<>() {
    @Override
    public ListCell<Contacts> call(ListView<Contacts> lv) {
        return new ListCell<>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Contacts item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                setText(empty ? "-" :( "[" + item.getContactID() + "] " + item.getContactName()));
            }
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this helps me see the outline of how these works!